# random numbers (using random.randint) returning None

Tags: python, list, variables, random

I'm trying to get a random number that is not used (already printed).
here's my code:

```
import random
used_numbers = []

def generate_random_number():
    num = random.randint(1, 90)
    if num not in used_numbers:
        used_numbers.append(num)
        return num
    elif num in used_numbers and num == generate_random_number():
        generate_random_number()

for i in range(90):
    print(generate_random_number())
```

For some reason after like 20 numbers it returning "None"..

Even if I tried switching to set, I'm still getting alot of "None"s.

**What I'm Expecting to get**:

A random number from 1 to 90 that is not used, for example:

```
1
90
82
53
34
65
21
86
```

ex.

Before I was getting something like this:

```
34
34
34
12
53
34
12
12
17
18
10
23
12
```

ex.

Comment: What is the point of `and num == generate_random_number()`? In any case, the `None` comes from the second branch of the if statement lacking a return.

Comment: Also -- if all you want is a permutation of 1-90, form the list `nums = list(range(1,91))` and then use `random.shuffle(nums)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) to guarantee the uniqueness of numbers and a while loop to iterate until you have a previously unseen number.

So, your function becomes:

```py
import random
used_numbers = set()

def generate_random_number():
    num = random.randint(1, 90)
    while num in used_numbers:
        num = random.randint(1, 90)
    used_numbers.add(num)
    return num

for i in range(90):
    print(generate_random_number())
```